# How to via a button scroll down to the bottom of page (through a specific javascript-function)

Tags: javascript

This might be a silly question. I want to use the following javascript-function to scroll down to the bottom of the page instantly, instead of to the top. How would you configure it to do just that? The script does look like this at the moment:

```
  <script>
        function scrollWindow()
        {
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
    </script>
```

The expected results is for the script code to scroll down to the bottom with the click of a button, instead of to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Or

```
var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);
scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
```